# RedirectToRoute Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

**Environment:**

I am working in WebAPI. I implemented all CRUD methods.

**Scenario:**

In PUT method, i am excluding some properties like 'CreatedDate' to be updated. My Code like below;

```
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(MyModel myModel)
{
    //Parsing to Business Entity   
    var item = TheFactory.Parse(myModel);
    bool result = await _myBL.UpdateLab(item);
    if (!result)
    {
        return BadRequest("Error in Save");
    }
    //Converting to view model and return
    return Ok(TheFactory.Create(item));
}
```

**Problem:**

Here i am not getting CreatedDate from user. So it always min date.In DAL i specified this field as not modified so it always have the created data value. In return i am converting to viewmodel from the model user given. So CreatedDate is min date not original.

**MySolution:**

So to avoid that get the updated object from the Database again and return to the user. I already have get method to return the object by passing id. So i just changed my PUT method like below;

```
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(MyModel myModel)
{
    //Parsing to Business Entity   
    var item = TheFactory.Parse(myModel);
    bool result = await _myBL.UpdateLab(item);
    if (!result)
    {
        return BadRequest("Error in Save");
    }
    //Redirect to getbyid method 
    return RedirectToRoute("GetById", new { id = item.Id });
}
```

**Issue:**

Here i thought i can reuse the method get method so it also returns ok(object). But after changed to this I got the following exception;

**The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.**

The response status is 405. Please help me to find the routecause

Answer (score -1):

You need to just call `GetById(item.id)`

```
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(MyModel myModel)
{
    //Parsing to Business Entity   
    var item = TheFactory.Parse(myModel);
    bool result = await _myBL.UpdateLab(item);
    if (!result)
    {
        return BadRequest("Error in Save");
    }        
    return GetById(item.Id);
}
```